# No entiendo la diferencia entre ob_end_flush() y ob_flush()

Tags: php, web

Estoy investigando sobre el tema de limpiar el búffer en PHP y en la web del manual de PHP me he encontrado con  ob_end_flush() y ob_flush(). He leído las descripciones de ambas funciones, pero no comprendo del todo la diferencia, quisiera aclararme, Gracias de antemano.